# Get all users with specific permission?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

How can I get all users that have specific permission?
for example we need to enumerate to all users that permitted to specific permission. code like this

```
var v=_userManager.GetAllUserWithSpecificPermission("ISO.Report.ReportV1");
foreach(var t in v)
{
   Logger.Info(t.UserName);
}
```

Comment: There is no such a method. You should use repositories to directly query yourself from AbpPermissions table (see table columns to understand it)

Comment: @hikalkan If you put such a method to userManager or permissionManager it can be useful. Thanks for this awesome framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a query to filter users by a permission. This may guide you:

```
var query =     from user in UserManager.Users
                join ur in _userRoleRepository.GetAll() on user.Id equals ur.UserId into urJoined
                from ur in urJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join up in _userPermissionRepository.GetAll() on new {UserId = user.Id, Name = input.Permission} equals
                new {up.UserId, up.Name} into upJoined
                from up in upJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join rp in _rolePermissionRepository.GetAll() on new {RoleId = ur.RoleId, Name = input.Permission}
                equals new {rp.RoleId, rp.Name} into rpJoined
                from rp in rpJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (up != null && up.IsGranted) || (up == null && rp != null)
                group user by user
                into userGrouped
                select userGrouped.Key;

var users = await query.ToListAsync();
```