# Query cannot be translated EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I using asp.net boilerplate and try to filter users via bool flag and permissions.

Here is code of method

```
private async Task<List<User>> GetAdminUsers()
    {
        using (UnitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
        {
            
            
            var adminUsers = await _userManager.Users.Where(x => x.IsFuelAdmin && _permissionChecker
                .IsGranted(new UserIdentifier(null, x.Id), 
                    FuelAdministratorPermissions.Pages_Administration_Missing_PreQual_LoanAmount_Email_Notifications))
                .ToListAsync();
            
           
            
            return adminUsers;
        }
    }
```

But it failing with this error

> ionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter  : The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(u => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(((ISoftDelete)u).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_1 || ((IMayHaveTenant)u).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
> .Where(u => u.IsFuelAdmin)
> .Where(u => ___permissionChecker_0.IsGranted(
> user: new UserIdentifier(
> null,
> u.Id
> ),
> permissionName: "Pages.Administration.QualificationChecks.LoanAmount_Email_Notifications"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: The error is clear. The LINQ query can't be translated to SQL. There's no way to translate local function calls like `IsGranted` to SQL

Answer (score 1):

There is no "IsGranted" function on the db server. You couldn't use IsGranted as a db function.

If you want to use the local C# `IsGranted` get the adminUsers into a C# local list and filter then for IsGranted:

```
var adminUsers = await _userManager.Users.Where(x => x.IsFuelAdmin).ToListAsync();
```

For a full SQL query you have to build a join query with your users over:

userRoleRepository, userPermissionRepository, rolePermissionRepository

Check out the accept answer:
[Get all users with specific permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839047/get-all-users-with-specific-permission)

Answer (score -1):

You could define additional property - say, IsAdmin - and set it in the runtime before that query.